# direct link to windows 10 defender exception list

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Might look like a stupid question, but in the good old Windows7 there where direct cpl "commands" you could paste in the "Run..." window to jump directly to a specific applet in the control panel. But since the old control panel is now replaced by the new Metro "Settings" app, I cannot find a way to go **directly** to the "page" where the **Windows Defender Exceptions** are listed.

for example: "appwiz.cpl" you could use to open directly the "Programs and Features" applet.

Is there a **command** to directly open the "**windows 10 defender exception list**" from crtl+R (run window) as from the user interface it are too many clicks to get there... and I use that very very very often.

Answer (score 0):

Try:  [Win Defender Commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-antivirus/command-line-arguments-microsoft-defender-antivirus)

Open cmd.exxe with Run as Administrator.

Then use the option to check for exclusions.

-CheckExclusion -path  Checks whether a path is excluded

That should work and there are many other useful command lines.

In c:\programdata\microsoft\windows defender\platform and then Version (use DIR to see versions), run MpCmdRun  /?  to see all the options.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip, did not know the existence of "**MpCmdRun**". Unfortunately I could not find a command in the help to **Add a new exclusion path**. Then I found on StackOverflow a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233123/windows-defender-add-exclusion-folder-programmatically) trough PowerShell:

```
powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command "Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath 'C:\your exclusion folder'"
```

This worked like a charm.